# Prometheus pushgateway Counter inc not correctly

Tags: python-3.x, prometheus

Prometheus pushgateway counter inc not correct，maybe pushgateway just support set value?

[image]

the value always be 1, not inc as expect.

code show as below:

```
class PrometheusClient(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.push_url = "prometheus-pushgateway:9091"

    def push(self):
        registry = CollectorRegistry()
        c = Counter('news_crawler', 'crawl count', labelnames=['source', 'source_name'], registry=registry)
        c.labels(source=2, source_name='jin_flash').inc()
        push_to_gateway(self.push_url, job='news_crawler_collector', registry=registry)
```

Comment: What library are you using ?

Comment: @aclokay python 3.8 and prometheus-client==0.7.1

Comment: You create a new counter and increase it once, why would you expect values other than 1?

Comment: @MichałPolitowski I got that, thanks a lot

Comment: @ MichałPolitowski I think the problem still exist. The Counter will be recreated as new Counter When restart the service and the value will be reset to 0. Can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

adjust the code with creating counter when init

```
class PrometheusClient(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.push_url = "prometheus-pushgateway:9091"
        self.registry = CollectorRegistry()
        self.counter = Counter('news_crawler', 'crawl count',
                               labelnames=['source', 'source_name'], registry=self.registry)

    def push(self):
        self.counter.labels(source=2, source_name='jin_flash').inc()
        push_to_gateway(self.push_url, job='news_crawler_collector', registry=self.registry)


cli = PrometheusClient()
```

Answer (score 0):

when querying the data use the increase function. https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase

this will give you how much the counter increased and not the current value of the counter.
When you run the application twice what happens is a counter reset, the increase function will detect that.

If you have multiple application increasing the same counter you should have a way to distinguish them with different tags, such as "host", "pid" or something else.

Answer (score 0):

I realize it has been a while since you posed your question and you may have likely found an answer. However, I still want to provide a response as the other answers have not addressed the issue. The behavior you've observed is expected, because the Pushgateway does not aggregate data. It merely serves as a metrics cache that stores any values pushed to it, enabling the Prometheus server to scrape these values. Consequently, invoking an inc() function will simply overwrite the previous value to 1.

For further understanding, consider reviewing the "Non-goals" section of the Pushgateway repository: https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway

*The Pushgateway is explicitly not an aggregator or distributed counter but rather a metrics cache. It does not have statsd-like semantics. The metrics pushed are exactly the same as you would present for scraping in a permanently running program. If you need distributed counting, you could either use the actual statsd in combination with the Prometheus statsd exporter, or have a look at Weavework's aggregation gateway. With more experience gathered, the Prometheus project might one day be able to provide a native solution, separate from or possibly even as part of the Pushgateway.*